A dual write proxy for Cassandra to aid in data migrations
We're planning to migrate data from one Cassandra cluster(Apache Cassandra) to another cassandra cluster(Apache Cassandra). Looking for a dual write proxy for Cassandra to aid in data migration from One cluster to another cluster without down time.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

You can use zdm-proxy to perform dual write to two Cassandra clusters.
Take a look at DataStax's zero downtime migration process documentation.

Thanks yukim. We tried with  zdm-proxy. we're seeing the error like "Couldn't start proxy, retrying in 10s: error initializing the connection configuration or control connection for Target: host could not be found in the secure connect bundle json configuration". As per doc we have to download secure connect bundle from Astra portal. My case we're doing cassandra to cassandra and i placed all required files in secure bundle. But still complaining to connect target cluster.

level=error msg="Couldn't start proxy: error initializing the connection configuration or control connection for Target: host could not be found in the secure connect bundle json configuration."
time="2024-04-18T22:52:14Z" level=info msg="Initiating proxy shutdown..."
time="2024-04-18T22:52:14Z" level=info msg="Proxy shutdown complete."
time="2024-04-18T22:52:14Z" level=error msg="Couldn't start proxy, retrying in 10s: error initializing the connection configuration or control connection for Target: host could not be found in the secure connect bundle json configuration."

i am using config.json  format like  {
"contactPoints": ["<contact_point_1>", "<contact_point_2>"],
"port": 9042,
"ssl": true,
"authentication": {
"username": "",
"password": ""
},
"sslOptions": {
"enabled": true,
"truststorePath": "/path/to/secure-connect-target"
}
}

You don't need secure connect bundle if you are connecting to Cassandra. Use these env vars on "Quick start" on zdm-proxy: https://github.com/datastax/zdm-proxy?tab=readme-ov-file#quick-start

Thanks yukim! we're able to deploy the ZDM proxy server and application able to read but unable to do writes. seeing below error's.

level=warning msg="error sending request with opcode 4f70436f64652045584543555445205b307830415d and streamid 2: could not convert target EXECUTE response to raw frame: cannot encode body: cannot encode body message: cannot write EXECUTE options: invalid serial consistency level: ConsistencyLevel QUORUM [0x0004]"

Serial consistency level (don't confuse with consistency level, this one is used for lightweight transaction) should be set to either LOCAL_SERIAL (multi datacenter setup) or SERIAL (single datacenter setup).
I think your application is setting the wrong value.

Thanks Yukim! But SERIAL and LOCAL_SERIAL writes not supported.

Tried with ANY consistency, still getting message like "ANY ConsistencyLevel is only supported for writes". Our application has to do both reads/writes.

Getting this error from application end  Query; CQL [INSERT INTO legal_agreement_log (id,user_id,agreement_id,date_time_recorded,action,agreement_cache_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; Query timed out after PT2S
